# replacing characters in a CString C++

Tags: c++, mfc

I have an application that reads a CString and then copies it to the clipboard. However the CString in question (SEMSerial) is not quite the correct information I need to copy. I need the first 3 characters of that string ("LEO") to be replaced with "SmartSEM".

is there any way I can do this?

Below is my code.

```
void CBugsDlg::OnBnClickedBtnSem()
{
    CLeo32DB* DB = CLeo32DB::CreateMe();
    TCHAR serial[60];
    DB->DBGetSystemKeyString((LPTSTR)_T("SerialNumber"),(LPTSTR) _T(""), serial, 60);
    CLeo32DB::DestroyMe(DB);    

    CString SEMSerial(serial);

    CVersionTranslatomatic ver(::GetDesktopWindow());

    CString version = ver.GetMajorMinorVersionString() + " " + ver.GetVersionType() + " " + ver.GetBuildNumber() + " " + ver.GetServicePack();

    CString Data = SEMSerial + " " + version;

    HGLOBAL  hglbCopy;

    if( OpenClipboard())
    { 
        wchar_t *wcBuffer = 0;
        hglbCopy = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE,(Data.GetLength() + 1)*sizeof(wchar_t)); 
        wcBuffer = (wchar_t*)GlobalLock(hglbCopy);
        lstrcpy(wcBuffer, Data);
        GlobalUnlock(hglbCopy);
        EmptyClipboard();
        SetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT, hglbCopy);
        CloseClipboard();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at CString::Replace()?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the string variable that needs to be replaced?

Answer (score 0):

If it's always the first 3 characters you want to replace, you can use `CString::Mid(int)` which will cut them off:

```
CString newPrefix = "SmartSEM";
newPrefix += SEMSerial.Mid(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean the method Replace of CString class?

```
SEMSerial.Replace( _T("LEO"), _T("SmartSEM") );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
StringWithLEO= SEMSerial + StringWithLEO.Mid(3);
```